# Adjoint action of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ on a Cartan subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. We define the adjoint action of $G$ on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ like the map $\mathrm{Ad} \colon G \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ with $\mathrm{Ad}(g)(X) = g X g^{-1}$.
We define the Lie bracket like the map $\mathrm{ad} \colon \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ given by $\mathrm{ad}(X,Y) = [X,Y] = XY-YX$.

I know that we have relations like $\mathrm{ad}(h,f) = [h,f] = -2f$ when $f \in \mathfrak{g}$ is lower triangular and $h$ in Cartan subalgebra.
Can we deduce relations like that when we consider the action of the Lie group on a Cartan subalgebra? I.e. the value of $\mathrm{Ad}(F)(h) = FhF^{-1}$ for $F$ in the unipotent radical and $h$ in a Cartan subalgebra?

Comment: The question and answer seem to assume that $h=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ specifically. Of course in this basic case of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, everything else follows by scaling, but in general you will need root relations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the unipotent radical of what but I assume you mean of the subgroup of lower triangular matrices since $f$ is lower triangular (indeed you want it strictly lower triangular). The nilpotent radical $\mathfrak{n}$ of the lower triangular subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ is isomorphic to the unipotent radical in the lower triangular subgroup via its exponential map since $\mathfrak{n}$ is nilpotent. In other words, $F = \exp(f)$ for some $f\in\mathfrak{n}$. So you are trying to compute $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(f))(h)$ but this is the same as
$$\exp(\operatorname{ad}(f))(h) = h + [f,h]+\frac{1}{2}[f,[f,h]] + \dots$$

Now $[f,h]= 2f$ and $[f,[f,h]]=0$ and indeed the rest of the terms vanish. So $\operatorname{Ad}(F)(h) = h + 2f$.

Note this will of course extend to other $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ although of course it will get a little bit more complicated as we would need to account for different possibilities. For example, at what stage is $\operatorname{ad}^n(f)=0$, is $f$ a root vector and for which root, is $h$ a coroot and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It is very helpful. Just a question, how do you obtain the formula of $\exp(\operatorname{ad}(f))(h)$ in terms of brackets ?

Comment: For any representation $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ we can define $\exp(\rho(X)) := I + \rho(X) + \frac{1}{2}\rho(X)^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}\rho(X)^n + \cdots$. Note this is just composing $\rho$ with the usual "matrix" exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{gl}(V)\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$

Comment: Thank you again ! And why $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(f))(h) = \exp(\operatorname{ad}(f))(h)$ ?

Comment: That is a basic fact of the Lie group-algebra correspondence. For any Lie group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ we have $f(\exp(X)=\exp(df(X))$.